# how can I hide a dynamic dropdown menu when its blank

Tags: picklist, dynamic, menu

I understand the class='hide' in css but im trying to check when a certain field of my sobject is 'undefined' to hide the div but I keep getting error cant read property 0 of null. Ive tried checking if null but then I get null is undefined. tried checking if undefined but cant seem to get it right. heres some of my code...

component div that im wanting to hide

```
<aura:attribute name="statute" type="SObject"/>
<div aura:id="showStat" class='hide'>
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="dropStat" label="Select statute if multiple based on description" class="dynamic" change="{!c.onStatChange}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.statute}" var="stat">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!stat.Description__c}" label="{!stat.Description__c}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
</div>
```

JS helper code that Im using to accomplish hiding:

```
var msg = cmp.find("showStat");
var descriptionField = cmp.get("v.statute");
if(descriptionField[0].Description__c){
    $A.util.removeClass(msg, 'hide');
}
else if(!descriptioinField[0].Decrition__c){
    $A.util.addClass(msg, 'hide');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the way to do this is with an 
an aura if returns true if the isTrue="{!v.yourAuraAttribue}" returns true.
below is the code that worked for me

component:

`<aura:attribute name="statute" type="SObject"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.statute[0].Description__c}">
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="dropStat" label="Select statute if multiple based on description" class="dynamic" change="{!c.onStatChange}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.statute}" var="stat">
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!stat.Description__c}" label="{!stat.Description__c}" />
        </aura:iteration>
    </ui:inputSelect>
</aura:if>`